# QGIS Map white space issue

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am using GQIS for first time today.

I finally got around to taking one of my Pix4d outputs and pulling into QGIS to get contours etc.. so I got it working ok.. My issue I have now is in the project I have small map and when I pull into a print layout and then try to make it fit the paper the quality is horrible. So I have to assume thats because the input map. So from what I can tell I need to clip my map so its bigger in the canvas. If I hit the Zoom Full button I have lots of extra white space around my map. So I assume I have to make that map take up all the space and then when I pull into the print layout I'll have higher quality and I wont need to magnify. I have been looking for hours to find a way to just take the map and make it fit but coming up with all sorts of strange clip methods that I would think I dont need to do.

How do I make my map fit the frame before I pull it into Print Layout?

Running V 3.2
Scale is 1:1072
Magnifier 100%

[image: Here is the shot after I hit the expand icon at top.]
[image: Here is print layout]

Comment: Now that I redo it again and I zoomed on the print layout it didnt look that bad, first time I did it, it was super pixelated. Should you be able to zoom in fully on the print layout and not loose quality ? or is it dependent on the size of the map full frame that dictates the quality in the print layout ?

Comment: I did set the scale down to 500 and it still looked ok. When I first tried it, I changed the scale and it looked horrible. Not sure what I did different this time. So just wanted to know if there is any correlation with how much space the map takes up on the project vs the Print Layout.

Comment: I think I know what happened. When you first view the Print Layout after it renders its fine.. but if you then change the scale it will show you the render, the low res render and then it takes some moments, depending on CPU, to final render the nice view. I think I saw the initial and didnt wait for the full render to happen.